# How can two devices communicating over a secure channel come to a shared secret?

Tags: android, algorithm, cryptography

I have two Android devices running an app. The app uses the [Bump API](https://github.com/bumptech/bump-api-android) to exchange information with the goal to come up with a shared secret for later use.

Specifically, the shared secret will later be sent to a central server where the devices are then registered as a "couple".

I came up with two types of solutions, but there must be other ones as well.

1. Decide which of the two devices may generate the secret (e.g., by flipping a coin)
2. Let both devices input a part of the secret and combine them (e.g., multiplying or XORing the two contributions)

What is the best solution for this situation?

--EDIT--
I'm not trying communicate securely (I consider the Bump channel secure enough).
Rather, I'm trying to find the most elegant solution to this specific issue.

Comment: Whichever device talks to the central server, should generate the secret. If both talk, use XOR.

Comment: Couldn't you let the server generate the "shared secret" when the two devices are registering as a couple? Hard to tell without knowing more about what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 5):

[Diffie-Hellman key exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) immediately comes to mind.

Comment: That seems like overkill. Our goal is not to communicate securely (the Bump channel is secure enough for our purposes), but to minimize the amount of communication.

Answer (score -1):

Each device generates random data equal in length to shared secret and sends it to other device. Shared secret is a XOR of this two parts.

Even if one device is broken and generates only zero strings, shared secret will be still good.